# Creating entites in Dialogflow using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm trying to create entites in Dialogflow using node.js. The entity values will come from a JSON file. I'm currently testing it using postman. However, the entity values are not being separated and being combined in only one line. How do I fix this? Thank you

This is my sample JSON file that is being sent.

```
     {
"Entity_Values": [
    {
    "Value": "One",
    "Synonym":["Solo","1"]},
    {
    "Value": "Two",
    "Synonym":["Double","2"]}
    ],
"Entity_Name": "Sample"}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
function createEntity (inputEntityobj, EntityName) {
 const promises = [];
 let entity_values = {value:[], synonyms:[]};
 let inputEntity_values = [inputEntityobj];

 for (i = 0; i < inputEntityobj.length; ++i) {
  let inputEntity_values = [inputEntityobj[i].Value];
  let inputEntity_synonym = [inputEntityobj[i].Synonym];
  entity_values.value.push(inputEntity_values);
  entity_values.synonyms.push(inputEntity_synonym);
 }

 const sizeRequest = {
 parent: agentPath,
 entityType: {
  displayName: (EntityName),
  kind: 'KIND_MAP',
  autoExpansionMode: 'AUTO_EXPANSION_MODE_UNSPECIFIED',
  enableFuzzyExtraction: true,
  entities: [entity_values],
 },
 };
```

This code outputs

```
value: [ [ 'One' ], [ 'Two' ] ], synonyms: [ [ [Array] ], [ [Array] ] ]
```

And in Dialogflow, these are all in one entity entry instead of being in two separate entries.

Comment: Is the JSON provided at the 1st part will be the value assigned to `inputEntityobj`?

Comment: Yes the JSON value is assigned to inputEntityobj

Comment: I posted an answer, let me know if the creation of entity is the same with what you are expecting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON input is almost identical to the required object format for `entities` ([reference](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/Entity)) and will only need a little bit of tweaking to make it work. Using your JSON, I renamed the `Value` and `Synonym` to `value` and `synonyms`. Loop through `Entity_values` and push the key value pair to list `entityVal` and use it for the request.

```
'use strict';

const dialogflow = require('@google-cloud/dialogflow').v2;

var inputEntityObj =      {
"Entity_Values": [
    {
    "Value": "One",
    "Synonym":["Solo","1"]},
    {
    "Value": "Two",
    "Synonym":["Double","2"]}
    ],
"Entity_Name": "Sample"};

var obj = inputEntityObj['Entity_Values'];

// rename keys
var res = obj.map(item => {
  item.value= item.Value;
  item.synonyms= item.Synonym;
  delete item.Value;
  delete item.Synonym;
  return item;
});


var entityVal =[];
for (const entity in res){
        entityVal.push(res[entity]);
}

var projectId = 'your-project-id';
var entityType = { displayName: 'test', //hard coded value for testing purposes
        kind: 'KIND_MAP',
        autoExpansionMode: 'AUTO_EXPANSION_MODE_UNSPECIFIED',
        enableFuzzyExtraction: true,
        entities: entityVal,

};

var parent = `projects/${projectId}/agent`;
var request = { parent: parent,
        entityType: entityType
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(request, null, 2));

const client = new dialogflow.EntityTypesClient();
client.createEntityType(request);
```

See testing done below:

`request` structure:

```
{
  "parent": "projects/your-project-id/agent",
  "entityType": {
    "displayName": "test",
    "kind": "KIND_MAP",
    "autoExpansionMode": "AUTO_EXPANSION_MODE_UNSPECIFIED",
    "enableFuzzyExtraction": true,
    "entities": [
      {
        "value": "One",
        "synonyms": [
          "Solo",
          "1"
        ]
      },
      {
        "value": "Two",
        "synonyms": [
          "Double",
          "2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Created entity in dialogflow:

[image]